# how to design a class with complicated data type which includes multiple list and dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, class, inner-classes

I have a complicated data type in which I would like to create a class but I do not know how to design it, please help and see example data below, thank you.

```
"""
complicated_data_sample1 = {
name: "test_name"
description:"test_description",
type:"test_type",
its_all:  [ "overview":{"brand":"dell", "model":"11"}, 
        "Processor": {"Speed":"1222mhz"} 
      ]

}

complicated_data_sample2 = {
name: "test_name2"
description:"test_description2",
type:"test_type2",
its_all: [ "Memory":{"flash":"256", "ram":"8gb", "video":"1gb"}, 
        "network": {"switching":"supported", "ports":"16","features": ["f1","f2","f3"]},
        "dimension":{"width":"3","length":"3","height":"4"},

      ]
}

complicated_data_sample3 = {
name: "test_name3"
description:"test_description3",
type:"test_type3",
its_all: None
}
"""
```

I would like to design a class like this ..

```
class Complicated_data:
    name = "test_name"
    description = "test_description",
    type = "test_type",
    # its_all , don't know how to do this
```

so that in the future, I can call data1_name = Complicated_data.name

The its_all data is complicated because it changes list length and dictionary keys also changing.

Comment: That is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: In what sense complicated? It seems to me that the obvious way of store it is a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are dictionaries.

Comment: 1. `its_all` us a bad name because it doesn't explain what it means
2. since `its_all` is complicated, maybe try to simplify it first by creating a class for it (or multiple classes with an interface)

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks. I am designing a class which data of its_all is different. I gave some example data outputs.

Comment: As @Jorge says, It's not clear that you can't do what you want with just a plain dictionary - a dictionary item can hold any other object type and can be changed as required.

But, if you want a new class, do you want a class that has an attribute called `its_all` containing that information? Or, do you want, in the case of `complicated_data_sample2` the class that can assign attributes for `memory`, `network` and `dimension`? What do you expect to initialise you class with - will it be strings of data like in your example?

Comment: yes, it is the one in my example. I am thinking if I can nest a class like Complicated_data.its_all.overview, .. however on the complicated_data_sample2, overview is not on the its_all list.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are confusing class attributes with instance attributes.  Second, `its_all` appears to be a *dict* mapping strings to other dicts; no other specific schema seems to be applied, so we'll leave it at that. Third, we'll use an empty dict in place of `None` if there is no additional data to store.

We'll make this a dataclass to avoid some boilerplate code.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class ComplicatedData:
    name: str
    description: str
    type: str
    its_all: dict[str, dict] = field(default_factory=dict)


complicated_data_sample1 = ComplicatedData(
      "test_name",
      "test_description",
      "test_type",
      {
        "overview": {"brand": "dell", "model":"11"}, 
        "Processor": {"Speed": "1222mhz"} 
      }
)

complicated_data_sample2 = ComplicatedData(
    "test_name2"
    "test_description2",
    "test_type2",
    {
      "Memory": {"flash": "256", "ram": "8gb", "video":"1gb"}, 
      "network": {"switching": "supported", "ports": "16","features":  ["f1","f2","f3"]},
      "dimension": {"width": "3", "length": "3", "height": "4"},

     }
)

complicated_data_sample3 = ComplicatedData(
    "test_name3"
    "test_description3",
    "test_type3"
)
```

Nothing about the size or contents of `its_all` needs to be specified. If you know more about the structure of the dict, you can define a second type to use, so that you might use `dict[str, Component]` in place of `dict[str, dict]` as the type of `its_all`.